# (Commutative Banach algebra) Prove that $G(\mathcal A)$ be an open set in $\mathcal A$.

Tags: group-theory, banach-algebras

**UPDATE**

I have a problem:

> Let $\mathcal A$  be a **commutative Banach algebra**. 
>   Denote $G(\mathcal A)$ is the set of all **invertible elements** in $\mathcal A$.
>
> Prove the following assertions:
>
> - a) $G(\mathcal A)$  is a group under multiplication in $\mathcal A$;
> - b) $G(\mathcal A)$  be an open set in $\mathcal A$;

=========================================================

**For a)**: $G(\mathcal A)=\{x \in \mathcal A \  \mid \exists y:=x^{-1} \in \mathcal A \   \text{such that}  \ x • x^{-1} = x^{-1}• x = e\}$

I tried to use the definition of the group:

- $G(\mathcal A) \ne \emptyset$: Because $e \in G(\mathcal A)$;
- Associativity: Because $\mathcal A$  be a **Banach algebra**, so

i/ $x(yz)=(xy)z,\  \forall x,y,z \in \mathcal A$;

ii/ $x(y+z)=xy+xz,\  \ (x+y)z=xz+yz,\ \forall x,y,z \in \mathcal A$;

iii/ $(\alpha x)y=x(\alpha y)=\alpha(xy),\ \forall x,y,z \in \mathcal A, \ \forall \alpha \in \Bbb C$

Hence, for all $x, y$ and $z$ in $G(\mathcal A)$ then $(x • y) • z = x • (y • z)$.

- Closure

For all $x, y \in G(\mathcal A)$, the result of the operation, $x • y=y • x$, is also $\in G(\mathcal A)$.

- Inverse element:

For each $x \in G(\mathcal A)$, there exists an element $y:=x^{-1} \in G(\mathcal A)$ such that $x • x^{-1} = x^{-1}• x = e$, where $e$ is the identity element.

Therefore, $G(\mathcal A)$  is a group under multiplication in $\mathcal A \blacksquare$.

=============================================

**For b)**:  *$G(\mathcal A)$  be an open set in $\mathcal A$;*

I think that We need  to prove that

- $\exists U \subset G(\mathcal A) $, where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x \in G(\mathcal A)$
- And use [the implicit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) theorem.

===========================================

We apply the theorem:

> If $A$ is a Banach algebra, $x \in G(\mathcal A)$ and $h \in \mathcal A$ such that $\|h\| \le \dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}$ then $x+h \in G(\mathcal A)$.

**Proof**

- Since $\|h\| < \dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}$ we have:
  $$\left \| x^{-1}h \right \| \le \left \| x^{-1} \right \|\cdot \left \| h \right \|<\dfrac{1}{2}<1$$ 
  Whence, $e+x^{-1}h \in G(\mathcal A)$.

On the other hand, we have performed:
$$x(e+x^{-1}h)=x+h, x \in G(\mathcal A)$$
Hence, $x +h \in G(\mathcal A)$.

- Now, we'll show that, there exists an open ball with center $x \in G(\mathcal A)$ and radius $r=\dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}$ such that:
  $$B\left ( x;\dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1} \right )\subset G\left ( \mathcal A \right )$$

Indeed, We take $y \in B\left ( x;\dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1} \right )$ then $$\left \|y-x  \right \| <\dfrac{1}{2}\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}\overset{\text{theorem (*)}}{\rightarrow} x+(y-x)=y\in G\left ( \mathcal A \right )\square $$

==============================================

I have forgotten anything in my solution above?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: For (a), you forgot to mention that it is closed under multiplication.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522496/help-me-please-proving-the-theorem

Comment: Thanks **Prahlad Vaidyanathan**! I updated it, is it correct? Can you check it? .

Answer (score 1):

Hints for (b):

1) It suffices to prove that the identity element is in the interior.

2) Use a geometric series.

Comment: I'm sorry **Robert Israel** when I say that I don't understand your hints :( ! Please Can you write more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: What is the series for $(1 + x)^{-1}$?

Comment: The series representation:$$\dfrac{1}{x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n, \ \text{for} \ |x|<1$$
So what? Please, Can you explain further? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand line "1) It suffices to prove that the identity element is in **the interior**"? Please, can you clarify your comments above help me? Thanks!

Comment: The interior of $G({\cal A})$.  Then use continuity of multiplication.

Comment: As for the series, that works also in a Banach algebra (with $|x|$ replaced by $\|x\|$.

Comment: Yes,**Robert Israel**. If I follow  **Prahlad Vaidyanathan's guidance**, can you check it? I think that his approach is correct. Do you think so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Proof b)

suppose $a\in G(A)$. We have to show that there is $r>0$ such that $\parallel x-a\parallel <r$, then $x\in G(A)$. Take $r_{0}=\frac{1}{\|a^{-1}\|}$,  we show that $S_{r_{0}}(a)\subseteq G(A)$ . If $\parallel x-a\parallel < \frac{1}{\|a^{-1}\|}$, then
we prove that $x\in G(A)$. For $\parallel a^{-1}x-e\parallel=\parallel a^{-1}x-a^{-1}a\parallel=\parallel a^{-1}(x-a)\parallel
\leq \parallel a^{-1}\parallel \parallel (x-a)\parallel \leq \parallel a^{-1}\parallel \parallel \frac{1}{a^{-1}}\parallel=1$. So $a^{-1}x$ is invertible, thus $x$ is invertible, i.e $x\in G(a)$. So $S_{r_{0}}(a)\subseteq G(A)$.

Hint:Let $A$ is Banach space. If $a\in A$ and $\parallel a\parallel <1$, then $a\in G(A)$.We used from this hint in the proof of question.